# Replace detailDisclosureButton in rightCalloutAccessoryView with customButton in MKAnnotation in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, mkannotationview

I am trying to show a custom image in the rightcalloutAccessoryView of an MKAnnotationView in lieu of a disclosureButton but it is not appearing:

Here is my code:

```
    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton new];
    UIImage * rightImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue-car"];

    [rightButton setImage:rightImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
```

When I do the above, no image appears and nothing happens if you tap.

However, if I use the following, a detail discolosureButton, the image does appear and the callout is tappable.

```
annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

What is missing from my custom button code that prevents the button from appearing or doing anything?

Answer (score 0):

In your MKAnnotationView subclass, you can simply provide the view like this:

```
- (UIView*) rightCalloutAccessoryView {
    UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];

    // configure your view as you like...


    return aView;
}
```

What is missing in your code? Likely an action, e.g.

```
[rightButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(showDetailCallout:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This code will work because a nil target will make ios search for a suitable target (here it is the mapView delegate)

Actually according to the docs, your code should work (as UIButton is a subclass of UIControl, the mapView delegate's `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control` should get called.